# Custom action doesn't navigate to another site

Tags: javascript, custom-actions

I have an issue with custom action.

Here is the definition of my custom action:

```
  <CustomAction
          Id="GoToDefi"
          Title="Go To"
          Description="Go To"
          RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
          RegistrationType="ContentType"
          RegistrationId="0x01"
          GroupId="ActionsMenu"
          Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
          Sequence="1000">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:GoToFunction();"/>
  </CustomAction>
```

So basically this is bound to CT and in display item form when i click on it, it doesnt redirect to anywhere, it just refereshes and that is it.

Here is the function code:

```
function GoToFunction()
{
    //Some extra steps are done

     window.location.href = "www.google.com";
}
```

Any idea what am i missing?

UPDATE:

I noticed a bit strange behaviour, when i hover over my link, i see that it has javascript:_dopstostback(...); But not my script.

When i do the debugging, my script is wel being called, but i think this _doPostBack overwrites my changes.
I checkthed the html and i see following:

```
....
<tr>
<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" >
   <a id="....toolbartbl_rpControls_ct112" href="javascript:_doPostBack('ct1000....','')"/>
   <a id="....toolbartbl_rptControls_CT112_LinkText" href="javascript:myfunction();" />
</td>
```

I don't know why but there are 2 anchor elemenets, and i think that postback is breaking my redirection.

But if in my custom action i give url like that url='www.google.com' then both of  elements have href to www.google.com. But if i use any kind of javascript then it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an older version of IE? Previously IE hade problems with redirecting with href.
Try if this line of code works:

```
window.navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: No, this solution doesn't work either, and i tested and for example i can redirect to other page, if i use this call for example on document ready, but in the function it doesnt :(

Comment: Can you see if your method is actually loaded at all? And maybee try som console.log() to see that the code line is actually executed

Comment: yes, i noticed something strange, ill update my post in a sec

Answer (score 0):

how about removing the last part ;) :

```
function GoToFunction()
{
    //Some extra steps are done

     window.location = "www.google.com";
}
```

if it was 2010 it would of been easy ;) ,

try adding javascript:void so like this:

```
  <CustomAction
          Id="GoToDefi"
          Title="Go To"
          Description="Go To"
          RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
          RegistrationType="ContentType"
          RegistrationId="0x01"
          GroupId="ActionsMenu"
          Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
          Sequence="1000">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:void GoToFunction();"/>
  </CustomAction>
```

Comment: That's a valid answer, albeit not very informative as to why. window.location.href doesn't always work.

Comment: i tried this also but it didn't work :)

Comment: is this in 2010 or 2007?

Comment: it is SharePoint 2007

Comment: ammended my answer